# Проблемы с работой mean() в NumPy, когда используется apply() из pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
X = [[-2, 1, 2], 
    [-1, 0, 1]] # создается матрица
df = pd.DataFrame(X) 
def xss(x): # функция которая нормализует матрицу
  print(x)
  print(np.mean(x))
  return x-np.mean(x)/(np.max(x)-np.min(x)) # формула нормализации 
df.apply(xss)
```

Результат:

```
0   -2
1   -1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
-1.5
0    1
1    0
Name: 1, dtype: int64
0.5
0    2
1    1
Name: 2, dtype: int64
1.5
```

Я не могу понять откуда взялся среднее "-1.5"?

Comment: `(-2 + -1)/2 = -3 / 2 = -1.5`

Comment: Если я что-то в чём-то понимаю, то `x-np.mean(x)` должно быть в скобках: `(x-np.mean(x))`. Вам очень повезло, что у вас везде `max-min=1`, а если это будет не так, то ваша формула без скобок испортится. Попробуйте подставить например вместо `2` -> `3`.

Comment: А что касается среднего, то по умолчанию `apply` считается c параметром `axis=0`, т.е. тут по столбцам считается и `min` и `max` и `mean`. Вообще я не уверен, что вы делаете правильно, как именно вам нужно нормализовать матрицу - по столбцам, по строкам или в целом?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я понял теперь как работает функция mean()